# OpenGL - Where is the state set by glDrawBuffers stored?

Tags: opengl, shader, fbo

If I understand correctly, you can attach textures to an FBO and then use `glDrawBuffers` to link those attachment points to (fragment) shader output indices. Where is this latter state stored after a `glDrawBuffers` call? The currently bound shader, FBO, or is it a global OpenGL state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glDrawBuffer(s)` sets framebuffer object state.